# Valence command to open new window or iframe

Tags: iframe, desire2learn, valence

When inserting a URL into a D2L course through Valence how can you set the URL when clicked to open in a new window or iFrame?

The situation is that a vendor that does lecture / class recording is building an LTI integration with Desire2learn to allow course builders to map their course to the recordings that are hosted by the vendor, students then click the URL link that has been inserted but have it open in a new window.

An example of the Valence call being used by the vendor has been provided.

```
{"TopicType":3,"Url":"http://10.168.2.248/ivt/lmsmangeview.do?moduleCode=324","StartDate":null,"EndDate":null,"IsHidden":false,"IsLocked":false,"Id":78523,"Title":"Classroom Recordings","ShortTitle":"","Type":1}
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, when building an LTI integration as a Quicklink Remote Plugin, your service can pass back a return URL that species a `target=NewWindow` query parameter that will cause the Quicklink to launch into a new window.

However, currently the Learning Framework APIs around course content manipulation do not let you create Course Content link-type topics and specify (through the API) the method in which they open.

Because the LTI integrations built as Coursebuilder Remote Plugins expect you to do all the actual course content insertion out of band using Learning Framework API calls (to modify the course's content), you cannot currently control how the LMS will launch link-type topics.